# Adding data to a Javascript array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add data to an array, and getting a weird result.

```
var arr = [];

var obj1 = { data: ["a","b"]};
var obj2 = { data: ["c","d"]};

arr.push(obj1);
arr[0].data.push(obj2.data);

console.log(arr[0].data);

// 1) what i want: [ ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"] ]
// 2) what i get:  ["a", "b", ["c", "d"] ]
```

Any idea how can I set it up so that I get the data formatted like: [["a","b"],["c","d"]]?
Here's a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/oakley808/UCQ65/

Comment: Why are you creating objects if you only want arrays?

Comment: ^^What he said. Also, that's not a 'weird' result at all - you're inserting an array as an element into another array.

Comment: This is a simplified example. The objects actually are more complex.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the objects to demonstrate what you are trying to do with the arrays.

Comment: You're right. Let me try and clarify. What I actually need to do is add object1 to the array, then essentially merge object2 into object1. The data arrays within the objects are x,y coordinates, which is why i need them paired up.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var arr = [];

var obj1 = { data: ["a","b"]};
var obj2 = { data: ["c","d"]};

arr.push(obj1.data);
arr.push(obj2.data);

console.log(arr);
```

[image]

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi take a look at the picture, i have a array with 2 other arrays with 2 elements

Comment: You're right @BrunoCroysFelthes . But sadly the array 'arr' needs to contain objects. arr[{data[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]},...{},...{data[[x8,y8],[x9,y9]]}].  I think I oversimplified too much in my original post.

Comment: @MichaelOakley Do a better feddle, or post your original variable structure, then we can help you better.